# Searching in Drupal 7 custom content fields

Tags: drupal, search, field

I was wondering if there is a module which could be used for searching in Drupal 7 custom content fields. Meaning, I have created a custom content type called typeA with three fields FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, B and C get discrete values from a list.

What I am looking is a search tool, probably in a module, which will allow the user to set values for each field and perform search to find TypeA content instances matching the serach criteria.

Any know module doing that?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).  The main idea of Views is to display certain content and you can give parameters to search for as well.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to go through Views tonight. Searching around I found Search Views which would be perfect but unfortunately there is no port to D7. Only D6